# Struct and memory allocation with loop

Tags: c, struct, memory-leaks, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have been trying to free() the memory at the end however my instructor stated that I have created 3 malloc'd pointers (with the current settings).

NOTE: I would like as detailed explanation possible regarding the malloc/what's actually going on in memory.

I would appreciate guidance on what I can do to make sure there is no memory leak.

I have written the following.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define LUNCH_ITEMS 5
    #define REMAINING 2
    #define CHAR_SIZE 256

    int main(void)
    {
        struct Food
        {
            char *name; //name attribute of food
            int weight, calories;
        } lunch[LUNCH_ITEMS] = {{"apple", 4, 100}, {"salad", 2, 80},};
        int loopCount;
        //INPUT
        char *namePtr = NULL;
        for (loopCount = REMAINING; loopCount < LUNCH_ITEMS; ++loopCount)
        {
            char tempBuffer[CHAR_SIZE];
            printf("Enter name of item,the weight of item, and the calories in that item: \n");
            // store name string in a tempBuffer. weight and calories directly into lunch structure array address
            scanf("%255s %d %d", tempBuffer, &lunch[loopCount].weight, &lunch[loopCount].calories);
            // get the exact size of (memory of) the input string including add one for null char
            size_t exactMemory = strlen(tempBuffer) + 1;
            //dynamically allocate the exact amount of memory determined in the previous step
            namePtr = (char *)malloc(exactMemory * sizeof(char));
            // check if no memory is allocated for foodPtr
    if (namePtr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory available***\n Terminating Program");
        exit(1);
    }
    //store the pointer to it in the name member of the structure in
    //the current lunch array element.
    (lunch + loopCount)->name = namePtr;
    // Copy the food name (stored in tempbuffer) into the dynamically-allocated
    // memory using the memcpy function

            memcpy(namePtr, tempBuffer, exactMemory);
    //(lunch + loopCount)->name = namePtr;
        }
    //DISPLAY
        printf("Item                        Weight       Cals\n---------------------------------------------\n");
        for (loopCount = 0; loopCount < LUNCH_ITEMS; loopCount++)
        {
            int weight = lunch[loopCount].weight;
            int cals = lunch[loopCount].calories;
            printf("%-12.20s%22d%11d\n", (lunch + loopCount)->name, weight, cals);
            if (loopCount > REMAINING)
            {
                //(lunch+loopCount)->name = NULL;
                namePtr = NULL;
                free(namePtr);
                //free((lunch + loopCount)->name);
            }
        }
        //De-allocate all malloc'd memory
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

My output -

```
Item Weight Cals
-----------------
apple  4   100
salad  2    80
hello  22   33
maybe  44   45
right 100   200
```

Comment: Valgrind is a good tool for checking whether your program leaks memory or does other unwise things with memory. Using valgrind on your program may reveal several issues.

Comment: Since someone else will point it out, I'll do it: [do not cast the return value of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Note: `strcpy` (or even `strncpy`) may be clearer in your intent than `memcpy`.

Comment: As for the actual question: you run `malloc` in the loop, which happens three times. Thus, you have three `malloc`-ed memory items. You do free them, though I think you're off by one: `loopcount > REMAINING` will miss the third lunch item (index `[2]`), whose name was dynamically assigned with malloc.

Comment: Setting a pointer to null and then `free`ing it is clearly not correct

Comment: @Evert Thank you for the responses! unfortunately memcpy is the mandatory function given in the instructions.

Comment: @Evert When I run the program currently it finishes and has all the answers correct but the email submission corrector for the class says I have the dynamic memory errors. when I do change the code under the DISPLAY comment in the if block to >= REMAINING there is an error message about the point I am trying to deallocate has not been allocated

Comment: See MM's comment about that error.

Comment: Great! Got rid of the setting to null. Might I ask, what is Valgrind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the initialization loop:

```
for (loopCount = REMAINING; loopCount < LUNCH_ITEMS; ++loopCount)
{
    // The code inside the loop will be executed for
    // loopCount being equal to 
    //     REMAINING
    //     REMAINING + 1
    //     ....
    //     LUNCH_ITEMS - 1
    //
    // So in your case, you execute this code for
    // loopCount equal to 2, 3 and 4
}
```

In other words, the code inside the loop is executed 3 times, i,e, **you call malloc 3 times**.

In the same way, look at the loop where you release the memory.

```
for (loopCount = 0; loopCount < LUNCH_ITEMS; loopCount++)
{
    // you execute this code for
    // loopCount equal to 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4

    // ....

    if (loopCount > REMAINING)
    {
        // Since REMAINING is 2, you execute this code for
        // loopCount equal 3 and 4
    }
}
```

So the code in the body of the `if` is only executed **2** times. You really want to do it **3** times (i.e. for loopCount equal 2, 3 and 4). So you need to change the code to:

```
    if (loopCount >= REMAINING)  // Notice the = sign
    {
        // Since REMAINING is 2, you execute this code for
        // loopCount equal 2, 3 and 4
    }
```

Now regarding `malloc` and `free`. When you release memory, i.e. using `free`, **you must pass exactly the value returned to you by malloc**

In the initialization you saved the pointer like this:

```
namePtr = (char *)malloc(exactMemory * sizeof(char));
// ...
(lunch + loopCount)->name = namePtr;  // Save pointer
```

So it is `(lunch + loopCount)->name` that shall be used for `free`. Like:

```
    if (loopCount >= REMAINING)  // Notice the = sign
    {
        free((lunch + loopCount)->name);

        // Optional part but always after calling free
        (lunch + loopCount)->name = NULL;
    }
```

BTW: Notice that

```
(lunch + loopCount)->name
```

is the same as

```
lunch[loopCount].name
```

which many consider easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. My instructor had made it seem as though I had initialized 3 separate pointers with malloc (rather than being created by the use of malloc). I then became very confused and tore everything to shreds and started over a few times. Thank you very much for the detailed explanation on how things are used by malloc and free. I was not understanding the way malloc would behave after I set my pointer to a member of a struct. Also thanks for the very informative way of how to use NULL correctly, I researched a lot and must have misinterpreted syntax on SO.

Comment: Also your explanation really cleared up how I view the free() function. Really helped me understand the code I was writing in a very straight-forward way.

Answer (score 0):

I think your instructor's comment about 3 malloc'ed strings is a pretty strong clue. I notice you have an array of 5 items, with 2 items pre-populated. 5 - 2 is 3.

Also, please be aware that indexes in C start from 0. The 2 items you pre-initialize your array with will have index 0 and index 1. Index 2 will be the first entered data. Comparing that index using > 2 will actually cause you to skip over the index of the first piece of user supplied data.

Comment: When I run the program currently it finishes and has all the answers correct but the email submission corrector for the class says I have the dynamic memory errors. when I do change the code under the DISPLAY comment in the if block to >= REMAINING there is an error message about the point I am trying to deallocate has not been allocated. Is the error not in the Display area but in my first block with setting loopCount to '2'?